# Secure Folders in ASP.NET MVC4 SPA application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 , single page application developed using angular JS. I have a requirement to protect download of ngcontroller , ngmodule javascript files and angular views (tpl.html) files under a specific folder.

I am using custom forms authentication which sets forms authentication cookie upon validation from a web service.  Right now I am able to download above files without being authenticated. I tried to use location path to restrict folders where my ng* files are , but it is not working. I don't want to write any handler as such.

Can you please advise the best possible way to achive this. Application will be hosted under IIS7.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

If you need to restrict access to specific users or roles you could place a web.config like this in the appropriate folder. For example, this would deny anonymous users:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Learn more about the [authorization element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8d82143t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing a web.config file in the folder you want to prevent access to. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</confinguration>
```